# Segfault on push_back

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault, push-back

In piece of code below, I get a segfault on the line calling push_back():

```
CTrigger CTriggerManager::AddTrigger(const std::wstring& eventName)
{
    CTrigger trigger(eventName);
    m_Triggers.push_back(trigger);
    return trigger;
}
```

In case it is not clear from the code, I am trying to initialize an object `trigger` push it onto the back of a list `m_Triggers`. Can anyone please tell me why this might cause a segfault?

If needed, see the code in full context [here](https://github.com/zootzoot/0ad/blob/b5245afe20402a66ad55ae2f4d2727cc16f1f1e1/source/ps/TriggerManager.cpp#L25).

Comment: please post a complete but miminimal example that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the TriggerManger being used and declared?  I am betting that since it is crashing on the push_back, that the actual instance of CTriggerManager is null and the first access into a member variable (m_Triggers) is causing an access violation.

I see one declared here, but never instantiated:
world.cpp:

```
CTriggerManager* pTriggerManager = NULL;
```

Comment: Ah, that is very likely it. I'll have a closer look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the problem obvoiusly not in this function and even not in TriggerManager.h/cpp files -- both classes are really simple and naive. btw, to initialize `m_EventName` better to use initalization list in constructor, not an assign operator...

Try to use `valgrind` for example... may be it will show you smth interesting about a real reason... -- it seems you corrupt an internal list somewhere before call to `AddTrigger`...